# Provider not executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, provider

I want to implement a provider to do error-logging, but my provider is never called when an error is thrown.

My provider class looks like:

```
   namespace DynF
{
    public class LoggingProvider : System.Web.Management.BufferedWebEventProvider
    {

        public override void ProcessEventFlush(WebEventBufferFlushInfo flushInfo)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("logging!");
        }
        public override void ProcessEvent(WebBaseEvent eventRaised)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("logging!");
        }
        public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("logging!");
        }
        public override void Shutdown()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("logging!");
        }
    }
}
```

in my web.config I have:

```
<system.web>
  <healthMonitoring enabled="true">
    <eventMappings>
      <clear/>
      <add name="All Errors"
             type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent, System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             startEventCode="0"
             endEventCode="2147483647"/>
    </eventMappings>
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="LoggingProvider" type="DynF.LoggingProvider"/>
    </providers>
    <rules>


      <clear/>
      <add name="LogAllErrors"
        eventName="All Errors"
        provider="LoggingProvider"/>
    </rules>
  </healthMonitoring>
</system.web>
```

When running a testpage that throws a NonImplementedException, the LoggingProvider never outputs "logging!" (and no breakpoints no matter where put in the LoggingProvider class makes the application stop). I read [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/How_to_Write_a_Custom_Web_Event_Provider_for_ASP_NET_2_0.aspx) tutorial and as far as I understand it this should be enough to make it work.

What is it that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add buffermode to false.

```
<add name="LoggingProvider" type="DynF.LoggingProvider" buffer="false"/>
```